# how to fix iOS leak when flipping between two views

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

My iPhone app badly leaks when flipping back and forth between a main uiviewcontroller and a help uiviewcontroller .

Here is the source of the main view, followed by source of the help view.

MAIN VIEW - FLIP TO HELP.....................

```
// Changes from operational view to Help view.
- (IBAction)showHelp:(id)sender 
{    
    // End trial mode:
    self.stop_trial_if_started; 
    self.rename_trial_if_edited;

    // Switch to trial help:
    help_view_context = 0;

    HelpView *controller = [[HelpView alloc] initWithNibName:@"HelpView" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;

    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

    [controller release];
}
```

HELP VIEW - INIT.............................

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor viewFlipsideBackgroundColor];   

    help_scroll.editable = FALSE;

  return;
}
```

HELP - RETURN TO MAIN VIEW.........................

```
// User clicked the button to return to operational view:
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"help-  done");
    if( help_view_context == 0 ) {
        [self.delegate trial_help_DidFinish:self];  
    }else{
          [self.delegate file_help_DidFinish:self]; 
    }
}
```

MAIN VIEW - RETURN FROM HELP...............................

```
// Inits operational view when user changes from Help view back to operational view.
- (void)trial_help_DidFinish:(HelpView *)controller {
    NSLog(@"trial_help_DidFinish");
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    self.init_trial_operation;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a return statement in the viewDidLoad method?

Comment: You are probably leaking something inside the view.  The transitions are correct.

Comment: What objects are being leaked? (BTW this looks like an ordinary method call using dot notation: 'self.stop_trial_if_started; '. That's not really what dot notation is intended for; not great style there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a controller with ref count of 1 and a local reference each time `showHelp:` is called:

```
HelpView *controller = [[HelpView alloc] initWithNibName:@"HelpView" bundle:nil];
```

you are losing your reference to it at the end of this method.

You happen to have references to it in `done:` (self) and `*_help_didFinish` (controller), but you never release it in either of those locations.  Dismissing the controller is fine, but you also have to `release` it.

(Another option would be to never create a second one, and maintain an iVar to the original.)

Answer (score 0):

You could well be leaking on this line

```
controller.delegate = self;
```

What is your property declaration for the delegate. If it's anything other than assign, then you either need to change it (*preferred option*) or make sure you are releasing it in the `dealloc` method of `HelpView` controller.